# Detrend function in r

Tags: r

I am working on a regression model about the relationship of annual crop yield and weather parameters. The crop yields data are from 1960 to present, it clearly shows an upward trend. A lot of research shows this might due to technology improvement. In order to make the regression model more reliable, a detrending method could be applied.

Anyone working on the same topic knows how to **detrend the crop yields**? I have tried the detrend function from **pracma** package, and it doesn't seem to work.

How are a subset of corn yields data of two counties from 1960 to 1980 as an example,

```
>view(corn) 
year   county1   county2    
1960    50        52 
1961    69        79
1962    75        84
1963    77        87
1964    60        81
1965    81        99
1966    67        83
1967    96        103
1968    81        104
1969    81        84
1970    51        82
1971    91        115
1972    100       118
1973    102       106
1974    69        96
1975    96        107
1976    103       95
1977    98        62
1978    106       105
1979    111       136
1980    95        97
```

Anyone knows how to do this kind of detrending?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using the detrend function from pracma.
It works after adjusting your data format a particular way.

```
require(pracma)

#Create data frame with country data:
df <- data.frame(
  "country1"=c(50,69,75,77,60,81,67,96,81,81,51,91,100,102,69,96,
               103,98,106,111,95),
  "country2"=c(52,79,84,87,81,99,83,103,104,84,82,115,118,106,96,
               107,95,62,105,136,97))

#Transpose data frame, making a matrix in the process:
df <- t(df)

#Add dates as column names:
colnames(df) <- c(1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,
                  1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980)

#Apply detrend:
data.detrend <- detrend(df, tt = 'linear')

#Apply time series:
data.detrend <- ts(as.numeric(data.detrend),
                   start=c(1960,1), frequency=2)
str(data.detrend) #check date range

#Plot:
plot.ts(data.detrend)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. However, I don't quite understand why frequency=2 ? I have tried your method with all my data (i.e. 57 years 8 counties all together), the detrending procedure seems working, but I couldn't make the time series format right.

Comment: It's true that the frequency is one observation per year, which would normally result in frequency=1, but here we have multiple countries. So for simplicity, we can think of the frequency here as the number of countries. If using 8 countries, format the data in the same I have done but with frequency=8 instead; frequency should equal the number of rows when the data is formatted this way. Then when you're ready to run "str(data.detrend)", that should now show the correct range of years.

Comment: Excellent, glad to help. Please mark this as answered so that others with the same question can find it in the future.